# not able to display data in the table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to retrieve data from the mysql database using jquery.
I had tried both the methods ($.getJSON & $.ajax) but none of them produced desired results.

Though data is coming in the browser's console(netwaork tab), but it is not displayed in the table.

**my php file.**
    
The above code generates the desired json structure when viewed in browser.

**here is my jquery code.**
***(using $ajax method)***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var jsonobj = [];
$.ajax({
url: "reg_data_table_js.php",
success: function(data) {
//alert(data)
jsonobj = data;
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < jsonobj.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].id + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].firstname + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].lastname + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].email + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].zipcode + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].username + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].password + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].interest + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].relocation + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].position + "</td>"));
  tr.append($("<td>" + jsonobj[i].startdate + "</td>"));
  $("#jsondata tbody").append(tr);
 }
},
error: function(err) {
 alert(err)
}
})
```

**browers console image**
   [image]

Comment: Can you show the data in browser console.

Comment: can you share the html mark up as well as the json response

Comment: try `jsonobj = data.users;`

Comment: did that too, but not working ..

Comment: Posting a minimal, representative sample in the question itself is usually better than posting a screenshot. That one's particularly hard to read. If it was plain text, throwing it into a [JSON pretty printer](http://jsonprettyprint.com) usually makes the structure obvious, but no way I'm retyping that.

Comment: @bora.dev can you include the reponse?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get your JSON Response as an array to get your data like id, firstname, etc, ...

And try like @guradio said to use jsonobj = data.users

Hopefully I helped

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following for parse the json

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: I had done that previously but even that was not solving, but let me try once again though.

Comment: Give alert(data) after that line. then check it JSON have been converted to array or not?

Comment: Its solved. Basically it was a mix  combination of previous all the feedbacks.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys.